# Check if CTRL-C pressed Or batch wait for agreement

Tags: batch-file, rapidminer

I need to know how can I check in batch file if the second batch file which is opened in other command window has stopped (waiting for argument or process not successful).

```
@echo off
:loop
start /wait rapidminer-batch.bat -f C:\Users\AHM-PC\Documents\ccc.rmp
echo cmd stopped
pause
goto loop
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When called batch ends, it returns a value to `errorlevel`. It works for `call`, don't know if for `start` too.

```
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (
    echo failed
) else (
    echo success)
```

or call `exit /b <number of error>` in your called batch, to return specific value. Check `exit` for more details.

Comment: Thank You ! I have to use 'call' function.

Answer (score 0):

The normal method to provide interbatch communication is a `flag file`

Either you `create` a flag file in the main routine and wait for the `start`ed routine to delete it or wait until the `start`ed batch creates a file, and delete it.

eg

```
echo.>myflag.txt
start anotherbatch.bat
:loop
timeout /t 1 >nul
if exist myflag.txt goto loop
```

Here, the batch will wait until `myflag.txt` is deleted, which you do in the second batch. All you need is for the two routines to agree on a filename to use.